# Stack Overflow Careers can't find my invitation

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Clicking the invitation link gives me the following error message:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow Careers!
>
> Thanks for your interest in creating a profile on Stack Overflow Careers.
>
> We can’t seem to find that invitation. It’s possible that it has been used already or has expired.

This occurred after I got the "email address is already in use" error. And then logged out/in with my openid account (as suggested).  I tried logging back in to careers with the original username/pass I used. However it won't let me now that I have used an openid associated with the email I used to create the account.  So my invitation is stuck on an account sitting in limbo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are happening here. One is that you had two accounts - I've merged them, so you should be all set. The invitation should have registered to the account you created when going through the process - we'll look into that. In the meantime, I'll send you a new invite.

Comment: new invite worked resolved my issue. thx!  the email address "already in use check" is somehow different or missing on the create login page (the second page during the create flow does complain).